# How to obtain pieces of strings in a Windows Batch script given 2 formats

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I have a file, list.txt, that contains the following 2 lines (it can change and have 1 to many lines):

> \\homedir\dir1\dir2\dir3\TEST_NAME_DIRECT_2015-06.csv
>
> \\homedir\dir1\dir2\dir3\TEST_NAME_DETAIL_0615.DED

I need to not only grab that entire line, but I also need to grab PART of that line. The dates at the end of the file can either be _YYYY-MM or _MMYY and end with either CSV or DED in any Case.

I basically need this at the end of the day to use as parameters to a java call:

1. TEST_NAME_DIRECT.csv
   \\homedir\dir1\dir2\dir3\TEST_NAME_DIRECT_2015-06.csv
2. TEST_NAME_DETAIL.DED
   \\homedir\dir1\dir2\dir3\TEST_NAME_DETAIL_0615.DED

I need the filename without the date and then the complete filepath+name that's given above after.

I have the following code so far:

```
set file=\\homedir\dir1\dir2\dir3\list.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%file%) do (
     FOR /f "tokens=5 delims=\" %%a IN ("%%x") DO (
     echo %%a %%x
     )
)
```

First of all, inside the 2nd FOR loop, I can't do anything like 
    set newvar=%%a
newvar ends up being blank.  Is there some Regex or find functions I can use so that I can end up with a variable that ends up being the Filename without the date and keeping true to .csv or .ded? I tried Findstr but it tries to open "TEST_NAME_DIRECT_2015-06.csv" when I want to search on that actual string itself.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Does this *have* to be done in batch? Powershell is available on standard Windows installations these days..

Comment: Use the command modifiers. Read the last section of the FOR help.

Comment: I'm moving some of the work to Java to use to spawn threads, instead since I can't run the same Java jar in parallel from Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
   rem Get file name only, i.e. "TEST_NAME_DIRECT_2015-06"
   set "name=%%~Na"
   rem Change "_" by "." and get name only, i.e. "TEST.NAME.DIRECT"
   for %%b in ("!name:_=.!") do set "name=%%~Nb"
   rem Change back "." by "_" and complete the output
   echo !name:.=_!%%~Xa %%a
)
```

Comment: May I ask you to select this answer? Click on the green check-mark.